# How can I implement vosk speech-to-text in a Discord bot using Node.js and Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, speech-to-text

I am currently creating a bot that uses vosk AI to transcript conversations. so far I am able to make my bot join a call and say who is currently talking.

```
    const { SlashCommandBuilder} = require('discord.js');
    const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, NoSubscriberBehavior } = require('@discordjs/voice'); //, getVoiceConnection, VoiceConnectionStatus, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, StreamType
    const { Readable } = require('stream');
    //const { Model, KaldiRecognizer } = require('vosk');
    const vosk = require('vosk');
    //https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models
    const model = new vosk.Model('model/vosk-model-en-us-0.42-gigaspeech');
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName('connect')
            .setDescription('Join channel to start listening'),
            async execute(interaction) {
                let talkingUser;
                const ch = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'transcript');
                const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel;//(interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.user.id)).voice.channel; //gets current user id
                    if (!voiceChannel){ //if they are in a voice channel return an error
                        await interaction.reply({content: 'Error: The voice channel does not exist!', ephemeral: true});
                        return;
                    }
                    const voiceConn = joinVoiceChannel({
                        channelId: voiceChannel.id,
                        guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                        adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                        selfDeaf: false,
                    });

                    await interaction.reply({ content: 'Ready to listen!', ephemeral: true });
                    await performSpeechRecognition(voiceConn, model, ch);

                    // voiceConn.receiver.speaking.on('start', (userId) => {//'end' works too
                    //     //lis();
                    //     //console.log(voiceConn.receiver.SpeakingMap.on());
                    //     talkingUser = (interaction.guild.members.cache.get(userId)).displayName
                    //     console.log(userId, 'started')
                    //     //ch.send({content: `${talkingUser}: words`});
                    // })
            }
        }
        async function performSpeechRecognition(voiceConn, model, ch) {
            //const recognizer = new KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000);
            const recognizer = new vosk.Recognizer(model, 16000);
            recognizer.setWords(true);
            recognizer.setVoice(voiceConn);

            const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
            voiceConn.subscribe(audioPlayer);

            audioPlayer.on('data', (audioData) => {
                recognizer.acceptWaveform(audioData);
            });

            audioPlayer.on('error', (error) => {
                console.error('Audio player error:', error);
            });

            recognizer.on('result', (result) => {
                const text = result.text;
                console.log('Recognized text:', text);
                // Do whatever you want with the recognized text
                // For example, you can send it to a transcript channel:
                if (ch) {
                    ch.send({ content: text });
                }
            });

            recognizer.on('error', (error) => {
                console.error('Recognition error:', error);
            });
        }
```

*I am not sure how to implement [vosk](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models), I am getting an error saying `Error (VoskAPI:Model():model.cc:122) folder'...' does not contain model files. Make sure you specified the model path properly in Model Constructor. if you are not sure about the relative path, use absolute path specification.`* [but that's not my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69695446/where-should-i-put-model-files-of-vosk-speech-recognition-in-java-error-voskap) FIXED

My issue is I am not sure how to get the audio "recorded" to put into vosk in the first place, I did some research online and this is the best I can accomplish

```
    const lis = () => {
        const recognizer = new KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000);
        recognizer.on('result', (result) => {
            const text = result.text;
            console.log(`Recognized:`, text);
        });
        recognizer.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Recognition error:', err);
        });
    };
```

*I do not know if I need anything else for Discord to pick up the audio itself as a temp recording I tried other implementations but when I run it I get an error saying*

```
        const recognizer = new KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000);
    TypeError: KaldiRecognizer is not a constructor
```

the solution for [KaldiRecognizer](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/nodejs/demo/test_simple.js)

Comment: I have both files https://kaldi-asr.org/models/m14 and https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models the giga speech version. I don't think I need the gigaspeech I downloaded it because I can always downgrade. but I have both downloaded and in my `/Models/model/vosk-model-en-us-0.42-gigaspeech` folder

Comment: I figured out why I wasn't able to get the API to work, I am not sure why it works now but I still have the TypeError: KaldiRecognizer is not a constructor error and I do no understand why

Comment: `const recognizer = new vosk.Recognizer(model, 16000);` Kadli wa the issue, we fixed that, its not "solved" because I have yet to get the speech to text working, but I figured out the man issue